# Swift - Use of unresolved identifier 'map'

Tags: swift, dictionary, compiler-errors

I cannot find map in Swift. Anyone knows how to resolve this issue?

> Use of unresolved identifier 'map'

[image]

I was trying to run [this](http://www.g8production.com/post/121193375576/swift-split-array-with-map-stride-advance) code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is quite old Swift. `map()` used to be a global function in early Swift versions, but (like other global functions such as `filter`, `index`, ...) has been replaced by an  [instance method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018373-map) of the `Sequence` protocol in Swift 2:

```
let a = stride(from:0 , to: sections, by: 1).map {
    stride(from:$0 , to: tempDataSource.count, by: sections).map {
        tempDataSource[$0]
    }
}
```

For more information, see for example

- [What’s New in Swift 2](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1794-what-s-new-in-swift-2)
- [WWDC 2015: Protocol-Oriented Programming in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/)

Comment: Could you also have a look at this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55910290/avaudiosession-plays-sound-on-receiver-or-mic-switches-to-front?noredirect=1#comment98576729_55910290